# Adding Dynamic view inside Dynamic View

Tags: android, dynamic, android-linearlayout

Trying to create a form with dynamic functionally to add it.

Below is the image which the form had been created in my application.

[image]

Things u can do in this page.

1. By pressing **Green Plus Button** 
   Inflate the new particular  form dynamically. For clear under understanding another hotel form will be added under the static form and green plus will be below the dynamic form. we can add multiple forms
2. By pressing **ADD Button** Inflates dynamic pairs, which consists of Cont. Person and Cont.Number. see the below image for clear understanding. we can add multiple pairs.

[image]

Issue what i'm facing is when i add first dynamic hotel form by pressing **Plus Button** getting a successful form and in that **ADD Pair Button** is inflating properly .. When i add second Dynamic Hotel form by pressing **Plus Button** getting a successful form and in that when i  press **ADD Pair Button** the pairs is inflating in the first dynamic form not in the second. same leads to three, four dynamic forms...to n forms.

Half pasted `pagetwo.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="5" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="5" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_trip_2_Layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hotel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1.0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_back"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3.0dip"
            android:text=" * Hotel"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin_lay_hotel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/hotel_edit_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextdesign"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoFullscreen"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="Location"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/hotel_edit_location"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:autoLink="all"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextdesign"
                    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal|left"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoFullscreen"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                    android:lines="4"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="Room No / Name"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/hotel_edit_room_no_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextdesign"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoFullscreen"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Layout_hotelContName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="Contact Person"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/hotel_edit_cont_person"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextdesign"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoFullscreen"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Layout_hotelContNum"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="Contact Number"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/hotel_edit_cont_number"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextdesign"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoFullscreen"
                    android:inputType="phone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!--
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/hotel_cont_pair_delete"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/trip_add_delete_bg"
                    android:text="Delete"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>
            -->

            <!-- <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/hotel_scroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp" > -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/hotel_cont_pair_linearLayoutFormtriptwo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>
            <!-- </ScrollView> -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/hotel_cont_pair_add"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/trip_add_delete_bg"
                    android:text="Add"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="Check In"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/hotel_edit_checkin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextdesign"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoFullscreen"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="Check Out"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/hotel_edit_checkout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextdesign"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoFullscreen"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="Notes"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/hotel_edit_notes"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextdesign"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoFullscreen"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3.33"
                    android:text="Cost"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/hotel_edit_cost"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2.67"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextdesign"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoFullscreen"
                    android:inputType="number" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/hotel_edit_currency_type"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextdesign"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoFullscreen"
                    android:inputType="textCapCharacters" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!--
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/h_addset"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>
            -->
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewhotel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/hotellinearLayoutFormtriptwo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/hotel_addset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

required code `SecondPageActivity.java`

**Green Plus Button Onclick Action**

```
hotel_addset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        LinearLayout linearLayoutFormhotel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.hotellinearLayoutFormtriptwo);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            AddhotelLayout(linearLayoutFormhotel);

        }
    });
```

**Method AddhotelLayout()**

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
protected void AddhotelLayout(final LinearLayout linearLayoutFormhotel) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final LinearLayout hotelnewView = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.triptwo_hotelrowitem, null);
    hotelnewView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ImageButton hotelbtnRemove = (ImageButton) hotelnewView.findViewById(R.id.hotelimagebuttonremove);

    Button hotel_cont_pair_add_dynamic = (Button) hotelnewView.findViewById(R.id.hotel_cont_pair_add_dynamic);

    hotel_cont_pair_add_dynamic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final LinearLayout linearLayoutForm = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.hotel_cont_pair_linearLayoutFormtriptwo_dynamic);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final LinearLayout newConatctPairView = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.trip_contactpair, null);
            newConatctPairView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            Button delete_hotel_cont_pair = (Button) newConatctPairView.findViewById(R.id.commonPairRemove);

            delete_hotel_cont_pair.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    linearLayoutForm.removeView(newConatctPairView);
                }
            });

            linearLayoutForm.addView(newConatctPairView);



        }


    });

    //LinearLayout linearLayoutForm = (LinearLayout)activity.findViewById(R.id.hotel_cont_pair_linearLayoutFormtriptwo_dynamic);

    //hotelContPairAddDynamic(activity, hotel_cont_pair_add_dynamic);

    final EditText edithotelcheckin = (EditText) hotelnewView.findViewById(R.id.tripcreatetwoedit_checkin);

    edithotelcheckin.setTag("hotel_checkin");

    final EditText edithotelcheckout = (EditText) hotelnewView.findViewById(R.id.tripcreatetwoedit_checkout);

    edithotelcheckout.setTag("hotel_checkout");

    edithotelcheckin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            updatecustom.showDialog(edithotelcheckin.getTag()
                    .toString());

        }
    });

    edithotelcheckout
    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            updatecustom.showDialog(edithotelcheckout
                    .getTag().toString());
        }
    });

    hotelbtnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            linearLayoutFormhotel.removeView(hotelnewView);
        }
    });
    linearLayoutFormhotel.addView(hotelnewView);

}
```

Required more details ..? i'll edit my Que.

Comment: Please be more precise with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Such as you are dynamically inserting views you may have different vews with the same id. So when you searching for the container to add `final LinearLayout linearLayoutForm = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.hotel_cont_pair_linearLayoutFormtriptwo_dynamic);` it references to the first view instead of second. Try to use `findViewById` not globally but within the dynamically added view

Comment: i tried that,  not initializing globally but with in the dynamic added view. if that the solution i'm facing `Null Pointer Exception` when i try to `addView`.

Comment: I do not know where the view with id hotel_cont_pair_linearLayoutFormtriptwo_dynamic actually is. You should know better. Post additional layouts with that view id.

Comment: solved the bug before `findViewById` have to add our `parent dynamic layout`  reference so the ans. is `ourparentdynamicview.findViewById`. by this way I solved the `NullpointerException`.

Comment: That was what i meant by saying "Try to use findViewById not globally but within the dynamically added view"

Comment: Thanks for ur time @user527759